# Docker network settings and iptables NAT

Tags: docker, nat, nat-traversal

I have a server running inside a docker container, listening on UDP port, let's say 1234. This port is exposed in Dockerfile.

Also, I have an external server helping with NAT traversal, basically, just sending addresses of the registered server and a client to each other, and allowing to connect to a server by the name it sent during registration.

Now, if I run my container with `-P` option, my port is getting published as some random port, e.g. 32774. But on the helper server I see my server connected to it from port 1234, and so it can't send a correct address to a client. And a client can't connect at all.

If I run my container explicitly publishing my server on the same port with `-p 1234:1234/udp`, a client can connect to my server directly. But now on the helper server I see my server connected to it from port 123**6**, and again it can't send the correct port to a client.

How can this be resolved? My aim is to require as little addition configuration as possible from people who will use my docker image.

EDIT: So, I need either to know my external port number from inside the container to send it to the discovery server, which, as I understand, not possible at the moment, right? Or I need to make outgoing connections from the container and my port to use the same external port as configured for incoming connections - is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The ports are managed by docker and the docker network adaptor. When using solely -P then the port is exposed docker internally and accessible through docker linking. When using "1234:1234" then the port is mapped on a host port and directly available for a client and also available for linking.

Start the helper server with a link option "--link server container/name". The helper server will connect to host "server" on port 1234. The correct ip address will be managed by docker.

Enable docker to change your iptables configuration, which is docker default. Afterwards the client should be able to connect to both instances. Note that the helper server should provide the host ip and not the docker container ip address. The docker container ip address does only work inside the host where the docker network adapter is running.